# Transaction deserialization test vectors for Elements sidechain?

Tags: transactions, sidechains, testing, liquid

I'm working on adding support for Elements sidechain to  https://github.com/Simplexum/python-bitcointx/ library.

Transaction serialization/deserialization seems to be working, but to test it properly, I need samples of different transactions (with or without assets, confidential/unconfidential etc).

Preparing these samples by hand is tedious. Elements source contain tx_valid.json data, but it seems to contain only bitcoin transactions - if you try to decoderawtransaction() some of the data from that file with elements-cli, you get "TX decode failed"

I am not sure if it is possible to get real transactions from Liquid network - while blockstream.info have an explorer for Liquid, it does not show raw transaction data.

Is there a chance to get such sample data somewhere (besides generating it myself) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/elements-0.14.1/qa/rpc-tests/confidential_transactions.py generates various tranactions. I think I will be able to dump the txs and use them in my tests.